# Passing path list to another function

Tags: python, python-3.x

So this code was originally one function and with help I have broken it into two separate functions but I am still struggling to get it to work.  Any guidance would be appreciated

```
# -------------------------------------------
# Checks to see if listed folders exists and then deletes
# -------------------------------------------


def check_directory(path):
    # returns true if path is an existing directory
    return os.path.exists(path) and os.path.isdir(path)


dirs_to_delete = [
    'C:\Folder Here',
    'C:\Folder Here1',
    'C:\Folder Here2',
    'C:\Folder Here3'

 ]


def remove_directory(pathlist):
    for path in pathlist:
        if check_directory(path):
            shutil.rmtree(path)
            print(colored('Found ' + path + ' removing', 'green'))
```

I am calling this function with

```
remove_directory()     #Checks and Removes directories listed above
```

I am getting the following error when ran

```
remove_directory()  #Checks and Removes directories listed above
TypeError: remove_directory() missing 1 required positional argument: 'pathlist'
```

Comment: you need to pass `dirs_to_delete` to `remove_directory()`

Comment: You need to pass an argument to the function `remove_directory()`

Comment: Try: `remove_directory(dirs_to_delete)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass `dirs_to_delete` to the function:

`remove_directory(dirs_to_delete)`

Answer (score 2):

You have defined `remove_directory` to take a single positional arg, `pathlist`, however, that does *not* take a value of the variable `pathlist` in global scope:

```py
s = 100

def print_val(s):
    print(s)

# I have not given it a positional arg, so s isn't defined
print_val()
# raises TypeError because the scope inside the function
# doesn't know what s is

# Now i give it that value
print_val(s)
# 100
```

So for your problem, you need to pass that arg

```py
# This is how you call the function in your script
remove_directory(pathlist)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your post it appears that you are calling `remove_directory` without passing your list as desired,
Change your call to `remove_directory()` to `remove_directory(dirs_to_delete)`

Answer (score 1):

**Debugging**:

```
TypeError: remove_directory() missing 1 required positional argument:
```

**Because**:

The function `remove_directory()` expects a param in this case perhaps the `dirs_to_delete`

**Hence**:

```
def check_directory(path):
    # returns true if path is an existing directory
    return os.path.exists(path) and os.path.isdir(path)


dirs_to_delete = [
    'C:\Folder Here',
    'C:\Folder Here1',
    'C:\Folder Here2',
    'C:\Folder Here3'

 ]

def remove_directory(pathlist):
    for path in pathlist:
        if check_directory(path):
            shutil.rmtree(path)
            print(colored('Found ' + path + ' removing', 'green'))

remove_directory(dirs_to_delete)   # pass the list to the function here
```

Answer (score 0):

The remove_directory function expects the parameter `pathlist`

Since you did not add a default value for `pathlist`, calling `remove_directory()` fails.

Try:

```py
def remove_directory(pathlist=[]):
    for path in pathlist:
        if check_directory(path):
            shutil.rmtree(path)
            print(colored('Found ' + path + ' removing', 'green'))
```

or supply a list when calling the function:

```py
remove_directory([])
```